# Loading Module with Progress Bar

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, progress-bar, modularity

My application has a couple of modules which am loading as thus in my application.

```
<local:moduleloader url="Module1.swf" id="modulel" />
<local:moduleloader url="Module2.swf" id="module2" />
```

Then while loading each module I am showing the progress bar. The progress bar shows but does not go away. It remains above the whole frame of the application. The module loader is as follows:

(Also note that in Flex 3 the same works, but am using Flex 4 and in Fx 4 it does not)

```
<mx:ModuleLoader    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"  
                    xmlns="*" 
                    creationComplete="initTheModuleLoader()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.Application;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;    

            private var ParentApp:* = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;
            private var standin:DisplayObject;

            private function initTheModuleLoader():void {
                addEventListener("loading", onLoading);
                addEventListener("progress", onProgress);
                addEventListener("setup", onSetup);
                addEventListener("ready", onReady);
                addEventListener("error", onError);
                standin = panel;
            }

            private function onUrlChanged(event:Event):void {
                if (url == null) {
                    if (contains(standin))
                        removeChild(standin);
                } else {
                    if (!contains(standin))
                        addChild(standin);
                }
                progress.indeterminate=true;
            }

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private function onLoading(event:Event):void {
                //progress.label=languageXml.lastResult.progress.progressonLoading +' ' + url;//Loading module
                progress.label = "Loading module"  + ' ' + url;//Loading module
                if (!contains(standin))
                    addChild(standin);
                progress.indeterminate=true;
            }

            private function onProgress(event:Event):void {           
                //progress.label=languageXml.lastResult.progress.progressonProgress;            //Loaded %3%%...
                progress.label = "Loaded %3%%...";          //Loaded %3%%...
                progress.indeterminate=false;
            }

            private function onSetup(event:Event):void {
                //progress.label=String(languageXml.lastResult.progress.progressonSetup).replace('###',url)
                progress.label = "on SetUp"; 
                progress.indeterminate=false;
            }

            private function onReady(event:Event):void {
                //progress.label= String(languageXml.lastResult.progress.progressonReady).replace('###',url);
                progress.label = "onReady";
                if (contains(standin))
                    removeChild(standin);
            }

            private function onError(event:Event):void {
                //progress.label=languageXml.lastResult.progress.progressonError + " " + url;
                progress.label = "Error";
            }

            private function onUnload(event:Event):void {
                if (url == null) {
                    if (contains(standin))
                        removeChild(standin);
                } else {
                    if (!contains(standin))
                        addChild(standin);
                }
                progress.indeterminate=true;
                progress.label="Module " + url + " was unloaded!";
            }   
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Panel id="panel" width="100%"  borderStyle="none" >
        <mx:ProgressBar width="100%" id="progress"  source="{this}" />
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:ModuleLoader>
```

Anybody could help on this?

Comment: If you're using Flex 4 already, is there a reason you can't upgrade to 4.5 and use the new Module/Module loader?

Comment: Actually I just upgraded from Flex 3 to Flex 4. So for the moment I have to stick to Flex 4 unfortunately.

Comment: If you've already upgraded from 3 to 4, 4 to 4.5 won't be a problem at all.

Comment: I understand you J_A_X but the decision for the moment is that the project stays on 4. My bad luck..but eventually I will move to 4.5 in the near future. But is there any problem with moduleloader in 4??

Comment: Well, from the code, you seem to be using the mx version of the ModuleLoader (which is flex 3).  In Flex 4.5, a new ModuleLoader is available that you can skin and add a progress bar which is much easier to manage.

Comment: Hmm I will look forward into that..as I like Skinning. Actually I just solved the issue by replacing the <mx:Panel> by HBox or Group. It works now. Thanks for the above info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Firstly in Flex 3 putting the InitModuleLoader function in creationComplete works but in Flex 4 this method has to be specified in initialize.

Secondly the  does not show in Flex 4 (it does in Flex 3), so I replaced mx:Panel by mx:HBox or s:Group

Thats all and it work.

But as J_A_X suggested above its better to use the Fx 4.5 as it has a new moduleLoader thats skinnable which might render it pretty cool.

Comment: Can you clarify what should have been after "so I replaced by or" so it's possible to understand what you did, then mark this answer as correct, so others may learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

Your onReady handler removes the standin, but not the progress bar.

Comment: But the ProgressBar is in standin (the Panel) which should remove the ProgressBar logically. Nevertheless I tried doing removeChild(progress). The problem still persists.

Comment: progress is actually in panel.  Try removing that or changing its visibility.

Comment: you mean change the visibility of the panel? I tried it without much hope. Or do you mean that I need to remove the panel completely and have only the Progress Bar?

Comment: You said that progress was a child of standin.  According to the code you posted, progress is a child of the component with id "panel."  Try doing whatever you want to do to hide the progress bar to its parent container.

Comment: Also, is your onReady event even firing?

Comment: The module is loading when doing <local:moduleloader url="Module1.swf" id="modulel" /> in the main mxml. But I have put some trace in moduleloadeder.mxml on Init..it is not tracing. When I do same in Flex 3 it is ok. The issue is only in Flex 4.How to go around this?

Comment: I have put the initTheModuleLoader() in initialize instead of creationComplete. Now the events fire correctly but the Progress bar does not show at all now.